# having trouble setting up a minecraft server, whenever I run the .bat it errors out and I don't know why as it works on my Desktop fine, same setup

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to host a Minecraft server and I'm getting errors whenever I run the .bat for the server.

Here is the contents of the .bat file that starts the server

```
@ECHO OFF

:: When setting the memory below make sure to include the amount of ram letter. M = MB, G = GB. Don't use 1GB for example, it's 1G ::

:: This is 64-bit memory ::
set memsixtyfour=4G

:: This is 32-bit memory - maximum 1.2G ish::
set memthirtytwo=1G

:: The path to the Java to use. Wrap in double quotes ("C:\Path\To\Java\bin\java"). Use "java" to point to system default install.
set javapath="java"

:: Any additional arguments to pass to Java such as Metaspace, GC or anything else
set jvmargs=""

:: Don't edit past this point ::

if $SYSTEM_os_arch==x86 (
    echo OS is 32
    set mem=%memthirtytwo%
) else (
    echo OS is 64
    set mem=%memsixtyfour%
)

%javapath% -version

echo Launching forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar with '%mem%' max memory, jvm args '%jvmargs%' and arguments '%*'

:: add nogui to the end of this line to disable the gui ::
%javapath% -Xmx%mem% %jvm_args%  -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar %*
PAUSE
```

This code is supposed to get the proper version of java, which is a variation of 1.8, and start the server startup but when it runs all I get is this error

```
OS is 64
java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
Launching forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar with '4G' max memory, jvm args '""' and arguments ''
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:110)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:70)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        ... 3 more
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have no clue what is going on as I have tried the exact same thing on my desktop and it works.
All help is appreciated.

--- Update 5/23/2023 9:11am ---
I have tried to force the .bat file to use the proper version of java from a fresh install of jdk-8u351 and directing (used the file path to the bin directory which holds the java executable) the file to where "java" is when it set.

```
:: The path to the Java to use. Wrap in double quotes ("C:\Path\To\Java\bin\java"). Use "java" to point to system default install.
set javapath="java"
```

Comment: Hint: Compare the Java versions on the working and non-working computers.

Comment: Regarding your "update": the shown script doesn't demonstrate this change at all, it's still using `java`. Unless you've updated your environment variables (such that `java --version` reports something other than Java 19), then you haven't really changed anything.

Comment: I had put the file path to the folder that contained the exe for java 1.8 but I made that update from my other computer and was a bit rushed so I didn't copy over the file path. I will add it when I get done with work.